# MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'Bad value'

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-query

I'm having an issue with SpringBoot JPA where I need to get the list of users with certain roles.

Here is the sample user: (A user can have multiple roles)

```
{
    "email": "10f11a0453nec@gmail.com",
    "roles": [{
        "$ref": "roles",
        "$id": {
            "$oid": "60d84178af2e455f5d0d1702"
        }
    },
    {
        "$ref": "roles",
        "$id": {
            "$oid": "60d84178af2e455f5d0d1702"
        }
    }],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2022-01-28T17:24:51.550Z"
    }
}
```

Now I want to get the list of users who has either admin or user role.

Here is my query (Comparing an array with array):

```
@Query("{'companyId': ?0, 'isDeleted': false , 'roles': {$in : ?1}}")
List<User> findByCompanyIdAndRole(String companyId, ObjectId[] roleIds);
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'Bad value' on server test-core.cot3cettvoyx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:660) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:650) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:582) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:650) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:78) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:178) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.1.1.jar:na]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you using AWS DocumentDB or MongoDB proper...?

Comment: Yes @Buzz Moschetti I'm using AWS DocumentDB

Comment: This could be a JPA binding issue, a DocumentDB engine issue (DocumentDB is not full-feature compatible with mongo server-side although it does work with the mongo Java drivers), or both.   The query to answer your question is very straightforward (a `$match` followed by a `$filter` on the `roles` array) so it is something else.

Comment: What is the solution you suggest @BuzzMoschetti? I'm blocked on this. Please help me.

Comment: Since its been over a year, did you find a solution @Vasu.Youth ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just now and it turned out that when it happened, what I thought was an array, in reality was null. It works properly if the array is indeed an array and contains zero or more elements.